# How to cut addressing to external resource registry-1.docker.io in GitLab Code Quality Docker image?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How to cut addressing to external resource registry-1.docker.io in GitLab Code Quality Docker image?

I have docker image from the registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/ci-cd/codequality:0.85.24
After I injected this image to my .gitlab-ci.yml I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 52.55.168.20:443: connect: connection refused
Unable to find image 'codeclimate/codeclimate:0.85.23' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 3.224.96.239:443: connect: connection refused.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I understand that I can use a proxy to addressing this address, but access to external resources is denied in our gitlab registry.

However, this error occurs during the execution of the command in gitlab-ci:

```
- docker run \
    --env SOURCE_CODE="$PWD" \
    --volume "$PWD":/code \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private registry for pulling Code Quality images:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.html#configure-code-quality-to-use-a-private-container-image-registry

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you use a private registry for pulling Code Quality images, but since [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#use-code-quality-with-a-private-authenticated-image-registry) (October 2022):

> ### Use Code Quality with a private, authenticated image registry
>
> The Code Quality scanner downloads and runs container images to scan your code.
>
> Previously, you could pull these images from a custom image registry, but you couldn’t use a private registry that required authentication.
>
> Now, you can provide a registry username and password by [setting CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#configure-code-quality-to-use-a-private-container-image-registry) when you include the Code Quality CI/CD template.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#configure-code-quality-to-use-a-private-container-image-registry) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/355814).